# How to populate dropdown list with SwiftyJSON from Alamofire post request?

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, alamofire

I have a dropdown list which i would like to populate with data from an Alamofire post request.

I was using SwiftyJSON before to populate a table view. Now I added Dropbox-iOS-SDK and hope i can find out how to populate the dropdown list.

```
AF.request(URL_COURSES, method: .post).responseJSON
{
        response in
        //printing response
        //print(response)
        
        switch response.result {
            case .success (let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            
            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["courses"] {
                debugPrint (key) //key
                //debugPrint (subJson) //value

            self.myCourses.append(MyCourses(courseId: subJson["courseid"].rawValue as! Int,
                                                courseName: subJson["coursename"].rawValue as! String))

            }

            case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            }

    self.dropDown.anchorView = self.viewDropDown
    self.dropDown.dataSource = //here i would like to see the list of courseId and courseName or only courseName

    dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
    print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
    self.labelTitle.text = coursesArray[index]
}
```

I made a test with an array and the dropdown menu was working fine.

```
{

    @IBOutlet weak var viewDropDown: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    
    let dropDown = DropDown()
    let coursesArray = ["Mathematic 1","Geograhic 1","Astrophysics 1","English 1","French 1"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelTitle.text = "Select a Course"
        viewDropDown.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        dropDown.anchorView = viewDropDown
        dropDown.dataSource = coursesArray
        dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:(dropDown.anchorView?.plainView.bounds.height)!)
        dropDown.direction = .bottom
        DropDown.appearance().setupCornerRadius(5)
        DropDown.appearance().textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
            print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
            self.labelTitle.text = coursesArray[index]
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func showCoursesOptions(_ sender: Any) {
        dropDown.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but AF 5 can decode directly into a model with `Decodable`. `SwiftyJSON` is a great tool but has become obsolete meanwhile. Actually you do three conversions JSON -> Dictionary > SwiftyJSON -> Model. This is pretty inefficient

Comment: "i have a dropdown list"  What is a dropdown list?  Where does a guy named 'DropDown' come from?

Comment: how would you use model with Decodable in my example?

Answer (score 0):

declare the string array variable to store name of courses :

```
var arrCourseName : [String] = []
```

then create a method for storing a name of courses in earlier created array:

```
func setCourseName(){
    arrCourseName = []
    myCourses.forEach { (json) in
        arrCourseName.append(json["coursename"].stringValue)
    }
    dropDown.dataSource = arrCourseName
}
```

call above method right after the getting data from api.

Comment: i took your code and put in my func getCourses. as you see above.

Comment: i get the error: 'Value of type 'MyCourses' has no subscripts'

Comment: i found solution: NSArray to String Array ... just for all people who read this